# django unique for each date

Tags: django, django-models, unique

First of all let me show you my model:

```
class ChannelStatus(models.Model):

        channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel,unique_for_date="date")

        date = models.DateField()

        platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)
```

Right now, when I want to make an ChannelStatus entry, there cant be more than one entry which is the same channel and  the date.Now, I want to change this as the uniquess of each channel to the date for each platform, so different platforms can have several same channel with same date. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what about this. (Untested code.)

```
class ChannelStatus(models.Model):

        channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel)

        date = models.DateField()
        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('channel', 'date')



class ChannelM2M(models.Model):
    channel_status = models.ForeignKey(Channel)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, unique = True)
```

[Old answer]

```
 class Meta:
    unique_together = ('channel', 'date', 'platform')
```

Btw, I would change the name of the second field from date, one you are working with datetime, and sometime do `from datetime import date`, you are going to get bitten

Comment: thanks but seems like unique_together is not supported for Manytomany fields :S

main.channelstatus: "unique_together" refers to platform. ManyToManyFields are not supported in unique_together:

main.channelstatus: "unique_together" refers to platform. This is not in the same model as the unique_together statement.

Comment: Added a new answer does that help you?